# C# change text color on one cell in grid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, colors, grid

I have a grid that I want to make one random cell a certain color. How do I get the code to color this one text in the cell to be yellow. Here is what I have in the method so far

```
 private void LunchOnly_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeFromMain();
        LunchGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        int chosen = RandoLunch(15);
        int gridrow = (chosen / 2);
        int gridcol = (chosen % 2);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean DataGrid?

Answer (score 0):

```
row.Cells[cell].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { BackColor = Color.Yellow };
```

"cell" is the index for the cell. You can use the string or integer index.